# All was happened due to his carelessness. All happened due to his carelessness

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, passive-voice

> All **was happened** due to his carelessness.
>   All **happened** due to his carelessness.

Which one is correct and why? Is first one in Passive voice? Please define it.

Comment: Using "all" in these examples does not seem natural to me. I would prefer "Everything was happening..." or "Everything happened...".

Comment: Please define what, exactly?

Comment: The past perfect of "happen" is "had happened". The verb is like the verb "exist".  "Happen" is intransitive, and so a passive cannot be formed from it.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "All was happened..." is incorrect. But if you're using passive voice, you could say

> All was happening due to his carelessness.

Or this might sound a little more natural:

> Everything was happening due to his carelessness.

The second sentence in your question is correct as-is.

You can say "All heppened" or "Everything happened". Or you can say "All was happening" or "Everything was happening". But saying "All was happened" is not correct grammar. "Was" describes a state of being -- all was quiet, all was well, all was chaotic, all was happening. But "happened" is a one-time past event, not a state of being, and cannot follow "was".

Comment: Chad, Why can't we say?

Comment: You can say "All heppened" or "Everything happened". Or you can say "All was hapening" or "Everything was happening". But you can't say "All was happened". "Was" describes a state of being -- all was quiet, all was well, all was chaotic, all was happening. But "happened" is a one-time past event, not a state of being. Don't know how to explain it any better than that -- it's just not correct.

Comment: *All was happening* isn't passive.  Neither is *Everything was happening*.